# Running a Tor relay behind Firewall

Tags: firewall

I'm trying to install a relay on a VM on Ubuntu.
I follow the manual and all looks ok, except it says I should open a port on my firewall to be reachable from the outside...
I have no access to the company router and all ports are closed.
Is there a way to bypass the firewall?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

if it's(a firewall you can't manage directly) not supporting UPnP - there's no way. You can use a VPN service with static IP : you're connecting from outside, obtaining an IP address **inside your box** and you're ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was looking something like reverse ssh embedded on Tor since VPN is offer as a service.

Comment: you should try a hidden service on this PC that will enable you to SSH to this hidden service for example. If it will not work at all and no port opening will be possible - then try VPN